# What is the difference between JOIN USING and JOIN ON?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In general, is there any difference in result set or query performance between:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tableA JOIN tableB USING (id);
```

and

```sql
SELECT * FROM tableA ta JOIN tableB tb ON (ta.id = tb.id);
```

If so, what is the difference?

Pros / Cons to using one over the other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you say `USING`, then the columns are treated differently in the query:

- Both tables must have the same columns and names for the `join` keys.  (I think this is a good practice anyway, but `USING` requires it.)
- The keys used for the join can only be used without a table alias in the rest of the query.
- If you do `SELECT *`, then the join keys are only returned once.

Comment: "Both tables must have the same columns and names". You mean, same names of columns which are join keys, right?

Comment: @ЕгорРогов . . . Yes.  Fixed.